# To append all rows from one table to another

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3. Suppose I have two sql-queries which return two tables with completely the same column names. For instance:

```
(SELECT id, partner_registration_date
FROM partner) as tbl1
```

and

```
(SELECT id, partner_registration_date
FROM partner_statistic) as tbl2
```

I need to return a table `tbl` such that `tbl_ROW_SET = tbl1_ROW_SET ∪ tbl2_ROW_SET` and `tbl_COLUMN_SET = tbl1_COLUMN_SET = tbl2_COLUMN_SET`

Comment: You want `union all`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you. I just haven't known about one's existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first case you can simply try:-

```
SELECT id, partner_registration_date
FROM partner as tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, partner_registration_date
FROM partner_statistic as tbl2;
```

And for second you can try with:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, partner_registration_date
FROM (SELECT id, partner_registration_date 
      FROM partner as tbl1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id, partner_registration_date
      FROM partner_statistic as tbl2);
```

Hopefully this helps you.